# Installing .NET 4 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net

Need to install .NET 4 on Windows 2008 Server.

Do I just use the Web Installer?
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992

It needs to run ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will do it. This is the 'online' installer so will require an internet connection throughout the install process. IIRC this is also offered through windows/microsoft update, which you will still need to run afterwards to ensure any post-release patches for .net 4 are installed.

You can also download the "standalone" installer from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7), which contains the whole package. This may be useful if you want to build a "library" of the stuff you installed in your environment, or if you will be installing on more than one machine.

Depending on what you're planning to do, you might also look at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=NETFX4RTM).